# How to pass REST API data into a specific database in mongodb while now everything goes to test by default?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

I am using Spring Boot to implement REST API which is connected to Mongodb. However, all the data updates are passed into the default database called test. Currently I have done these:

1. I have opened mongodb server and client, and changed connected database on client side using cmd $mongo myDatabase
2. Postman is used to test spring boot, things go well there, just the updates all go to test instead of myDatabase
3. I cannot really find the Bean file, in which I suppose the configuration changes should be made?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please share your code which is used to connect to mongo and how are you executing query.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you need to specify different database name. It can be done using  Common application properties.
Refer http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Add

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Your Database name
```

in your application.properties file